# Save Javascript Elements into mysql database using jquery/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I am trying to get users IP Details in the browser which is working well but I want to save these values into mysql database. As per my knowledge it is doable with php and ajax but how do I do that here.

My Code

```js
<iframe id="iframe" style="display: none"></iframe>
        <script>
            //get the IP addresses associated with an account
            function getIPs(callback){
                var ip_dups = {};

                //compatibility for firefox and chrome
                var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                    || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                    || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

                //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
                if(!RTCPeerConnection){
                    //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
                    //
                    //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                    //<script>...getIPs called in here...
                    //
                    var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                    RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                        || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                        || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                    useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                }

                //minimal requirements for data connection
                var mediaConstraints = {
                    optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
                };

                var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

                //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
                var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

                function handleCandidate(candidate){
                    //match just the IP address
                    var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                    var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

                    //remove duplicates
                    if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                        callback(ip_addr);

                    ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
                }

                //listen for candidate events
                pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

                    //skip non-candidate events
                    if(ice.candidate)
                        handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
                };

                //create a bogus data channel
                pc.createDataChannel("");

                //create an offer sdp
                pc.createOffer(function(result){

                    //trigger the stun server request
                    pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

                }, function(){});

                //wait for a while to let everything done
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //read candidate info from local description
                    var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

                    lines.forEach(function(line){
                        if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                            handleCandidate(line);
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }

            //insert IP addresses into the page
            getIPs(function(ip){
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.textContent = ip;

                //local IPs
                if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);

                //IPv6 addresses
                else if (ip.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2].appendChild(li);

                //assume the rest are public IPs
                else
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].appendChild(li);
            });
        </script>
```

```html
<h4>Your local IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <h4>Your public IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <h4>Your IPv6 addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
```

I assume the last part of the Javascript which is -

```
if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);

                //IPv6 addresses
                else if (ip.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2].appendChild(li);

                //assume the rest are public IPs
                else
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].appendChild(li);
```

This is where the IP is displayed, I want to put it my database everytime the webpage is opened.

Comment: Storing something in a mysql database using jQuery & php usually just involves making an ajax call with jQuery to a php page with whatever data you want to save and then saving that data via PDO...have you read up on using jQuery with php and mysql?

Comment: @ZackMacomber : Thanks for the reply. yes I have read that but Javascript is way more confusing for me. I can do a insert query using php but how do put the javascript variable - document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]. into php variable is what I am not able to figure out.

Comment: You don't need to; you can get the IP address on the server.  If you want a value from the client, you'll need AJAX.

Comment: @SLaks : I am using this code to get both private and public IP which is exactly what I want. How do I use ajax here to save those in a database ?